# GEdit -- highlight starting tag - ending tag of selected HTML?

Tags: html, gedit, gedit-plugin

Is there a plugin [or a way out ?] to highlight the selected HTML's starting tag - ending tag ? Probably something like which is present in Notepad++  ?

To show with an example, when we select the  `<div>` tag below, it automatically higlights its closing tag  `</div>` tag

```
 <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
 </div>
```

**[edited]** 
  Sorry. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, Gedit 2.30.3.

Comment: Please note that plugins for gedit 2 and gedit 3 are incompatible and you should specify which version your using.

Comment: I do not know for sure if I understand your question but can take a look at plugins gmate. https://github.com/gmate/gmate

Comment: Sorry about this. I'm using Gedit 2.30.3, Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

Try Zen Coding plugin:

"Zen Coding is a plugin for high-speed HTML, XML, XSL (or any other structured code format) coding and editing. The core of this plugin is a powerful abbreviation engine which allows you to expand expressions - similar to CSS selectors - into HTML code."

On the official page there is no information about Gedit version, so probably the 2.* is supported.

https://github.com/mikecrittenden/zen-coding-gedit

http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/